# Rails 5 actioncable undefined method `fetch' for nil:NilClass

Tags: websocket, redis, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I am using Rails 5 with `actioncable` and I am getting [this error](https://gist.github.com/adham90/e385b2b5bbd6800e0b9a) when trying send anything that throws `actioncable` What should i do?
I'm trying to push the project to Heroku.

```
NoMethodError in MessagesController#create

undefined method `fetch' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #37):

#35       # Also makes sure proper dependencies are required.
#36       def pubsub_adapter
*37         adapter = (cable.fetch('adapter') { 'redis' })
#38         path_to_adapter = "action_cable/subscription_adapter/#{adapter}"
#39         begin
#40           require path_to_adapter

Extracted source (around line #50):

#48       # Adapter used for all streams/broadcasting.
#49       def pubsub
*50         @pubsub ||= config.pubsub_adapter.new(self)
#51       end
#52 
#53       # All the identifiers applied to the connection class associated with this server.

Extracted source (around line #42):

#40           def broadcast(message)
#41             server.logger.info "[ActionCable] Broadcasting to #{broadcasting}: #{message}"
*42             server.pubsub.broadcast broadcasting, ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(message)
#43           end
#44         end
#45     end


Rails.root: /media/adham/Data/code/rails5test

Application Trace
app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:6:in `create'
app/middleware/chat_action_cable.rb:10:in `call'
```

Comment: It sounds like `cable` is `nil` when `cable.fetch` is called. Is that the case?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There was a commit made here: [enter link description here](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/56a9341689942146d350ff931497956a15152bdb)

Reading through and changing the config file for ActionCable from...

`config/redis/cable.yml`

to

`config/cable.yml`

...fixed the issue. This update is to allow the ActionCable backend to be agnostic.

Comment: Can someone explain why this happens ? It happened to me also with Rails  5.0.0.beta2

Comment: They changed the configuration file to be more ambiguous to an ActionCable backend,  instead of defaulting to Redis.